# Files inside a docker image disappear when mounting a volume

Tags: docker, mount, docker-volume, mounted-volumes

Inside of docker image has several files in `/tmp` directory.

Example

```
/tmp # ls -al
total 4684
drwxrwxrwt    1 root     root          4096 May 19 07:09 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May 19 08:13 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        156396 Apr 24 07:12 6359688847463040695.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        150856 Apr 24 06:46 63596888545973599910.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        142208 Apr 24 07:07 63596888658550828124.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        168716 Apr 24 07:12 63596888674472576435.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        182211 Apr 24 06:51 63596888734768961426.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        322126 Apr 24 06:47 6359692693565384673.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4819 Apr 24 06:50 635974329998579791105.png
```

When I type the command to run this image -> container.

```
sudo docker run -v /home/media/simple_dir2:/tmp -d simple_backup
```

`Expected behavior` is if I run `ls -al /home/media/simple_dir2`
then the files show up.

But `actual behavior` is nothing exists in `/home/media/simple_dir2`.

On the other hand, if I run the same image without the volume option such as:

```
sudo docker run -d simple_backup
```

And enter that container using:

```
sudo docker exec -it <simple_backup container id> /bin/sh

ls -al /tmp
```

Then the files exist.

TL;DR

I want to mount a volume (directory) on the host, and have it filled with the files which are inside of the docker image.

### My env

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Docker 19.03.6

Comment: You map an empty folder into your image and you are wondering why it is empty inside of your container? Also, what exactly is what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Smutje Mapped empty folder to my image when it run. Is make trouble? My achieve is get the files out from image to host os directory.

Comment: And you think overriding a folder will achieve this? No, map it to a different folder and copy the containers contents into this second folder.

Comment: @Smutje Ty bro. Genius. You saved my life. So, if host os's directory is empty, then container's directory will override is that right?

Comment: I would assume so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

> Mount into a non-empty directory on the container
> If you bind-mount into a non-empty directory on the container, the directory’s existing contents are obscured by the bind mount. This can be beneficial, such as when you want to test a new version of your application without building a new image. However, it can also be surprising and this behavior differs from that of docker volumes.

> So, if host os's directory is empty, then container's directory will override is that right?

Nope, it doesn't compare them for which one has files; it just overrides the directory inside the container with the directory on the host, no matter what.

Comment: But there are two types of mounts "volume" and "bind". I understood that the "volume" config defaults to "type=volume" if you omit the explicit type assignment. 

Docker documentation is very bad.