# docker volume mount removes existing files

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

Is there any way to fix the below issue:

Docker volume mount removes existing files in the /apps/conf directory.

```
volumes={
    '/apps/conf': {
        'bind': '/apps/conf',
        'mode': 'z,rw'
    },
    '/data/deployment/logs': {
        'bind': '/data/deployment/logs',
        'mode': 'z,rw'
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't *remove* the files, it masks them, just like any other filesystem mount. Put the files somewhere else, and then copy them into `/apps/conf` when the container starts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Files inside a docker image disappear when mounting a volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61886645/files-inside-a-docker-image-disappear-when-mounting-a-volume)